# Mouse disappears after unlocking/waking after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-10, mouse, cursor, logitech-mouse

Ok, thus far, I haven't been able to find my specific issue online, so I'm turning to you guys.

I recently upgraded from Windows 8.1 to 10 (pro). Sometimes (not every time) when I unlock or wake up my computer, my mouse will become invisible.  It still works, I can still hover and click stuff, I just can't see it.

In addition, I can't lock my computer after that (nothing happens when I press Win+L). Only restarting my computer will fix this, and when I do restart, it hangs up on the "Restarting" message, like it's trying to log me off or something, and won't restart.  I am forced to hit the reset button.

I am using a high-end desktop with Windows 10 pro. I've tried:

- Reinstalling mouse drivers
- Changing my cursor appearance
- Refreshing the desktop
- Turning on the mouse trail

And none of those fixed it.  I am using a Logitech wireless mouse and keyboard with the SetPoint software installed, but I've been using that setup for years before with no problem.

Thanks, any help is appreciated.